# Error at getSupportFragmentManager() - android

Tags: android

Is there a way possible to use getFragmentManager() function without extending Activity or any other class?

Comment: If you have an activity reference in that class, you can use it to call getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way possible to use getFragmentManager() function without extending Activity or any other class?

The concept of fragments and `FragmentManager` is purely something used by activities, nothing else. To get a `FragmentManager`, you need an activity, as only the activity should care about the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
public class MyTestClass{

     public void myMethoName(Activity activity){
         FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();

         // Now you can use fm as Object of FragmentManager
     }

 }
```

Hope it will help you.